# Expected class, Delegate, Enum, Interface or struckt error in C#

Tags: c#

I have this error and i don't know how to fix it, i can't find whats wrong with my code so i ask help to the ppl that are reading this and know the solution.
The error is at the button voids(exept the start button void). tried to switch between the URLtexbox and the Combobox but somewhere i screwed up, i've tried a lot to fix it but i couldn't find out how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web;

namespace ****
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        }

        private void startbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (Text)
            {
                case "full":
                    {
                        webBrowser1.Navigate(URLtextbox.Text);
                    }
                    break;

                case "empety":
                    {
                        webBrowser1.Navigate(comboBox1.Text);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

        private void stopbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Stop();
        }

        private void forwardbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoForward();
        }

        private void backbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoBack();
        }
}
```

Thanks for helping ^.^

Comment: Your switch doesn't refere to any variable

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois Actually it does, there is a "Text" property on the main form. Its probably not what was intended, but it is valid.

Comment: Ow ok, since the is no properties shown i thought that could have been a futur issue so just wanted to point it out

Comment: Its inherited from `Form` so it doesn't show up unless its overridden or shadowed.

Comment: I did "full" and "empety" on purpos for timely just so i can remember that if there is Text in the URLtexbox i know that it has to be the texbox what it has too look up

Answer (score 3):

The 3 methods (`stopbutton_Click`, `forwardbutton_Click` and `backbutton_Click`) must be defined inside a class.

Or in other words: Move the closing brace of the class below the last method.